# How can I change menu items text color in android material design?

Tags: android, material-design

In material design, I am facing problem to change menu text color. It only takes textColorPrimary's color. I have read & tried most of previously answered solution for this problem. But nothing worked, maybe I am missing something.

Below is my style :

```
    <style name="AppBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

I tried creating another style as mentioned in solution given in other question :

```
 <style name="ActionBarTheme"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

& using it on popup theme, but didn't worked. Toolbar is shown below.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/productListToolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarTheme"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
    />
```

Problem is shown below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your toolbar widget:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat
```